# Actionscript 3 Code Keeps Giving Error 1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I managed to apply this code, which fetches a text file and places it into a dynamic text box. Here's the code:

```
// reference code from permadi

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarMode;
import fl.controls.TextArea;
var mFileReference:FileReference;
stop();
// Setup button to handle browsing
browseButton.buttonMode = true;
browseButton.mouseChildren = false;
browseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBrowseButtonClicked);
// Hide progress bar;
progressBar.visible = false;
// This function is called when the BROWSE button is clicked.
function onBrowseButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("onBrowse");
    mFileReference=new FileReference();
    mFileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    var swfTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text Files","*.txt; *.html;*.htm;*.php");
    var allTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("All Files (*.*)","*.*");
    mFileReference.browse([swfTypeFilter, allTypeFilter]);
}
// This function is called after user selected a file in the file browser dialog.;
function onFileSelected(event:Event):void
{
    trace("onFileSelected");
    // This callback will be called when the file is uploaded and ready to use
    mFileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);

    // This callback will be called if there's error during uploading;
    mFileReference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);

    // Optional callback to track progress of uploading;
    mFileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

    // Tells the FileReference to load the file;
    mFileReference.load();

    // Show progress bar;
    progressBar.visible = true;
    progressBar.mode = ProgressBarMode.MANUAL;
    progressBar.minimum = 0;
    progressBar.maximum = 100;

    browseButton.visible = false;
}

// This function is called to notify us of the uploading progress
function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percentLoaded:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100;
    trace("loaded: "+percentLoaded+"%");
    progressBar.setProgress(percentLoaded, 100);
}

// This function is called after the file has been uploaded.;
function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference;

    // These steps below are to pass the data as DisplayObject 
    // These steps below are specific to this example.
    var data:ByteArray = fileReference["data"];
    codeText.text = data.toString();
    browseButton.visible = true;
    progressBar.visible = false;
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
}

function onFileLoadError(event:Event):void
{
    // Hide progress bar
    progressBar.visible = false;
    browseButton.visible = true;
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

    trace("File load error");
}
```

It works fine, I added the loaded file to a string, but now I want Flash to read the string and send it to the related frames corresponding to it. Here's the code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateFunction);
function updateFunction(e:Event)
{
    if (codeText.text == "Preference 01")
    {
        gotoAndStop(50);
    }
    else if (codeText.text == "Preference 02")
    {
        gotoAndStop(51);
    }
    else if (codeText.text == "Preference 03")
    {
        gotoAndStop(52);
    }
    else if (codeText.text == "Preference 04")
    {
        gotoAndStop(53);
    }
    else
    {
        gotoAndStop(54);
    }
}
```

I Keep Getting Error 1009 About A Null Object, I Tried For Hours But I Think I Need Some Help.

Comment: why you are running enterframe, I think you just need to call it once in the onFileLoaded method. Also do you have any code on those frame number ie 50,51,52,53,54 ?

Comment: Voted down. Why would you not make the simple effort to post the entire code error?

Comment: I'm new please go easy on me. I do have codes on the other frames, but the codes are simple control timeline stop();

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to go to a different frame based on what you loaded, simply remove your `updateFunction` and replace your `onFileLoaded()` function with the following:

```
function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference;

    // These steps below are to pass the data as DisplayObject 
    // These steps below are specific to this example.
    var data:ByteArray = fileReference["data"];
    browseButton.visible = true;
    progressBar.visible = false;
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);
    mFileReference.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

    codeText.text = data.toString();
    switch (codeText.text) {
        case "Preference 01":
            gotoAndStop(50);
            break;
        case "Preference 02":
            gotoAndStop(51);
            break;
        case "Preference 03":
            gotoAndStop(52);
            break;
        case "Preference 04":
            gotoAndStop(53);
            break;
        default:
            gotoAndStop(54);
    }
}
```

Please be sure to enable Debug mode and compile in that mode so you can get specifics like line numbers on your errors.